# MySql group and count by yearweek

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of user activity.

```
created_at   account_id
2017-01-01   1221     
2017-01-01   21458
2017-01-03   1221     
2017-01-04   1221
2017-01-04   4555
....
```

Right now I get the number of unique users (account_id) that were active during a certain week using this query.

```
SELECT YEARWEEK(created_at) as yearweek, COUNT(DISTINCT account_id) as count
FROM activities
GROUP BY YEARWEEK(created_at)
```

This returns

```
|yearweek|count|
================
| 201701 | 221 | 
| 201702 | 253 | 
| 201703 | 282 | 
| 201704 | 252 | 
| 201705 | 247 | 
| 201706 | 135 |
```

What I actually want to get is number of users that were active during a certain week or the previous 3 weeks.

In other words if a user was active last week, or 2 weeks ago or 3 weeks ago he should also count for this week. (4 weeks altogether) Obviously that user should also be counted in each of those previous weeks he was active in.

Is it possible to achieve this with MySql? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to count in a week, users that where active in that week or in one of the previous three weeks.

A simple way would be to *generate* user/week records accordingly (i.e. when a user was active in week #3, build fake records to pretend the user was active, too, in week #4, #5, and #6).

```
select wk, count(*)
from
(
  select account_id, yearweek(created_at) as wk from activities
  union
  select account_id, yearweek(created_at + interval 7 day) as wk from activities
  union
  select account_id, yearweek(created_at + interval 14 day) as wk from activities
  union
  select account_id, yearweek(created_at + interval 21 day) as wk from activities
) x
GROUP BY wk
ORDER BY wk;
```

(You can also use `UNION ALL` with `COUNT(DISTINCT account_id)` instead of `UNION` and `COUNT(*)`.)

Comment: I was able to use this even though on my dataset of 2 million rows spread over 2 tables it is a bit slow. (~7 seconds) Luckily it's for reporting purposes so it does not matter. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Could be you can use a period of 4 weeks  eg:

```
select count(distinct acccount_id) 
from activities
where created_at BETWEEN curdate( ) AND DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 4 WEEK)
```